# Undefined function 'PlainText' in expression

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've tried googling all over for this error but couldn't find it

I don't want to post the real code snippet but I'll leave something like this:

```
SELECT
    PlainText(HelpArea) AS Area,
    PlainText(HelpArea) AS Subject,
    FROM tblHelp;
```

I'm working on a data migration tool tying into MS Acces and my understanding is that the Plaintext function here is a function of the MS Access application and not the Access driver and it will fail anytime I try to use it from outside of the access application. The query I input in MS Access generates the table just fine but when working from outside of it, it doesnt work.

**My question: is there an alternative function I can use instead of Plaintext that will work?**

Really stumped here. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not a function, it is a method of the application object, therefore cannot be used outside of MS Access environment.

Comment: why was this tagged mysql and javascript?

Comment: You should a data migration tool that works from inside Access or your trouble will never end.

Comment: These comments weren't really much help. My question was, is there an alternative I can use instead of "Plaintext" that will work outside of MS Access.